# Why does zero inflated model zeroinfl give an error

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to train my data with the following model but I am getting this error and it doesn't let me run the code. Although, with the same model a colleague of mine get the same error but lets him run the code. I was wondering what could be the issue here.

```
> zip <-zeroinfl(tot ~ comm + prev_tot +  log(gdp) +
+                      athletes_avmedals | athletes_avmedals +prev_tot , 
                       data= train_data)
```

> Error: (converted from warning) glm.fit:
> fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that somewhere you have `options("warn")` set to a value >= 2. From `?options`:

> ‘warn’: integer value to set the handling of warning messages. ... If ‘warn’ is two (or larger, coercible to integer), all warnings are turned into errors.

Hopefully this was set by you and can be reset (e.g. set `options(warn = 0)`); if you're unlucky this has been set within package code and will be harder to change.

The clue is `Error: (converted from warning)` (emphasis added).